# Process 4 different video feed in opecv python

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, object-detection, yolo

I have CUDA 9.0 running on 1080 GPU (ubuntu 16.04), i have to process four different  video feed in opencv. what is best way to multiprocess in cuda & opencv ?

Comment: What have you tried? Are the feeds independent or must they be processed in lock-step? What processing is required?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Feeds are independent but same type of operation is to be performed on all input feed.actually i'm doing Vehicle counting using (YOLO for detection & Kalman filter for tracking) ,

Comment: Make life easy for yourself and write it for one camera and then run 4 independent processes so you get multi-processing and parallelism done for free.

Comment: I tried running all of 4 process as independent process using subprocess but it cause very low FPS 3-4.( when running on single feed FPS is about  20-23)

Comment: I meant make 4 entirely independent, totally separate Python scripts - then each one gets its parallelism for free from the OS and each one has its own GIL so they don't slow each other down.  At the shell you would do `./process 1 &` and `./process 2 &` and `./process 3 &` and `./process 4 &`